# Woocommerce отправка данных корзины в форму рассрочки

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет! Сижу, ломаю голову, ничего понять не могу.

В общем. Есть скрытая форма, которая должна передать данные корзины на страницу банка для оформления рассрочки.

Сам код:

```
<form action='https://loans-qa.tcsbank.ru/api/partners/v1/lightweight/create' method='post'>
    <input name='shopId' value='test_online' type='hidden'/>
    <input name='showcaseId' value='test_online' type='hidden'/>
<?php 
 global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

       $i = 0;
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            $prod = $_product->get_title();
            $quan = $values['quantity'];
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            $allprice = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
            echo "<input name='sum' value='$allprice.00' type='hidden'>";
            echo "<input name='itemName_$i' value='$prod' type='hidden'/>";
            echo "<input name='itemQuantity_$i' value='$quan' type='hidden'/>";
            echo "<input name='itemPrice_$i' value='$price.00' type='hidden'/>";
       $i += 1;
        }

?>
<input type=”submit” value=”Купи в кредит”/>
</form>
```

Получается, данный код передает название, количество и стоимость товара в данную форму. Но проблема в том, что если товар вариативный, то он берет только первую цену, а не ту, которую выбрал человек.

Советовали вставить вот такую штуку:

```
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="button-rassrochka" onclick="
    var price=jQuery('form.cart span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').html().split('<')[0].replace(' ', '');
    price = price * jQuery('form.cart .quantity input').val();
    jQuery('input[name=sum]').val(price);
    return true;
    " return="">Подать заявку</button>
Этот код при клике на кнопку считывает текущую html-цену товара из span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount, удаляет из неё html-код, удаляет пробелы, записывает цену в input[name=sum] вашей формы, и возвращает true, чтобы форма отправилась.
```

Но проблема в том, что у меня это не работает :( И я не могу понять что делать с этим... Очень прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Я уже думал реализовать это как-то на стадии оформления заказа, добавить туда данную форму/кнопку. Но не могу понять каким образом там брать данные о товарах. :(

Comment: А вы уверены что в `form.cart span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount` есть то что вам нужно? Смотрите что в консоле выводится. И у вас сейчас получается что значения из скрытой формы можно подменить вручную и нигде это не проверится.

Comment: Нет, не уверен. Проблема в том, что я не могу передать цену выбранного вариативного товара, а с простыми товарами все нормально. Например я положил в корзину товар, его стоимость от 10000 до 20000, я выбрал опцию за 15000, $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true); - эта штука не показывает выбранный вариативный товар, а показывает только его начальную стоимость. Вот я и не могу понять как мне сделать, что бы передавалась правильная цена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите как в стандартной корзине сделала фильтрация товара, в ней используется фильтр `woocommerce_cart_item_product` который получает тип продукта и всю информацию о нем
Вы можете так же использвать этот фильтр:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
$_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
$price = $_product->get_price();
}
```

Либо делать проверку вручную: в вашем примере `$values` это ассоциативный массив и если товар вариативный нужно выбирать поле `$values['variation_id']`, а не `$values['product_id']`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Вы очень-очень помогли в такой для меня сложной ситуации!!!)